# Writing into MySQL fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have an if tree that is failing at this point. I'm not sure why the php code is not writing into the MySQL database. Any help is greatly appreciated. The code fails sometime after line 1.

```
if ($numrows == 0) {

                                        $password = md5(md5("qkIa4".$getpass."qwenm"));
                                        $date = date("F d, Y");
                                        $code = md5("fekwe".$password);

                                        //insert user into db
                                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$password', '$getemail', '0', '$code', '$date', '$fn', '0')");

                                        //check if entry was made into db
                                        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                                        if ($numrows == 1) {


                                            //email the user code
                                        }
                                        else
                                            $errormsg = "An error has occured. Your account was not created.";
                                            echo mysql_error();
                                            echo $getuser;
                                            echo "<br />";
                                            echo $password;
                                            echo "<br />";
                                            echo $getemail;
                                            echo "<br />";
                                            echo $code;
                                            echo "<br />";
                                            echo $fn;
```

The code is only echoing the error that mysql_connect(); is deprecated. All variables are echoing properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change your mysql syntax to mysqli. it has been depricated in new mysql version

Comment: USE Mysqli versions of functions or Go For PDO

Comment: Needless to say about SQL injections, you are  not escaping strings before adding the to the database. I'd recommend using PDO (as opposed to mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is deprecated. You should not use native mysql functions, but instead turn toward mysqli.
Please read
[PHP.net about Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)